# Launching SQL injection in MD5 with mysqli_real_escape_string()?

Tags: php, exploit, sql-injection, mysql, md5

Can we exploit the `MD5()` and `mysqli_real_escape_string()` methods in this case to perform SQL injection?

Here is the code snippet:

```
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,MD5($_POST['pwd']));
$login = "select fnm,lnm,email,addr,age,dob from register where email='$email' and pwd='$pwd' and status='a'";
```

The full code is available [here](http://pastebin.com/WTxuf5Zp).

Comment: You really REALLY need to start using [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)(bcrypt) instead of MD5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think the `pwd` field is not exploitable in this example. Since the PHP is passed through PHP's [`MD5()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) function, the output will be the hexadecimal encoding of the hash. That means the string will only contain digits and the letters `a` to `f`. You can not break out of the quote using those characters.

Lets assume that instead `MD5($_POST['pwd'], true)` had been used, so that the raw binary hash had been returned instead. Then you would need to sneak in a `'` to escape out of the string context. Assuming [the character sets are configured correctly](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php) `mysqli_real_escape_string()` would block that.

So lets assume there was no `mysli_real_escape_string()`. Then you could possibly exploit this by crafting a password that when hashed produce an SQL payload. You would have to generate a lot of MD5 hashes to produce a useful payload by chance, but it is not impossible.

By the way, have you looked into the `$email` variable? Looks like it could be exploitable.

*Mandatory notice I: Just because this probably isn't exploitable in practice, don't be fooled to think it is safe to concatenate untrusted user input into SQL queries. Use prepared statements.*

*Mandatory notice II: Don't use MD5 to hash passwords.*

Comment: thanks for your answer mate!    But how the **$email** variable is exploitable?

Comment: @NITIN Looked at the full code, and it doesn't look exploitable to me. Unless there are some issues with the encoding, but I don't know how to test or exploit that.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any sanatisation on the email address input? If not you could put in "example@site.com' -- " into the email field (change the email field attribute type to text in the inspector if needed). This will comment out the password check so as long as a match is found with the email it will return true. SHA512 is better than MD5.

Comment: SHA512 is indeed stronger than MD5, but using a different hash algorithm wouldn't stop this injection attack.

Comment: @Lewis Self actually **$email =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,trim($_POST['email']));** is removing the spaces in the email and making the SQL injection to not work!

Comment: Yeah SHA512 won't stop SQL injection, but it is known to have collisions, better safe than sorry! Can I also ask how are you getting the 'a' status? is that checking the user has activated their account? I'm sure this can't be vulnerable to SQL injection though. I'd still recommend changing to SHA512 instead of MD5 though.

Comment: @LewisSelf yeah! **a** is for active account!

Comment: @LewisSelf your answer does not directly address the question, which seems to focus on `pwd` and its modifications.

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to mind me asking, I answered the original question but was just checking he wasn't leaving other areas of his code vulnerable. The other answer seems to ask the same thing about other parts of the code.